# Can't combine two datasets of GDP values (year by year) and US presidents (starting date - ending date)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have this dataframe of GDP:

```
date  GDP
1933   1.2
...    ...
2015   3.2
```

And another dataframe with US presidents like this:

```
 start              end            president               party                              
1933-03-04  1941-01-20  Franklin D. Roosevelt   Democratic  
1945-04-12  1953-01-20  Harry S. Truman         Democratic  
1953-01-20  1961-01-20  Dwight D. Eisenhower    Republican  
1961-01-20  1963-11-22  John F. Kennedy         Democratic  
1963-11-22  1969-01-20  Lyndon B. Johnson   Democratic  
1969-01-20  1974-08-09  Richard Nixon           Republican
... 
2017-01-20  2021-01-20  Donald Trump            Republican
```

How can I combine GDP by president term? The desired result is something like this:

```
start               end              president             party              GDP
1933-03-04  1941-01-20  Franklin D. Roosevelt   Democratic   (corresponding sum of GDP)
1945-04-12  1953-01-20  Harry S. Truman         Democratic   (corresponding sum of GDP)
```

Is there a way to achieve this without manually calculating and adding the values in GDP columns?

First, I've tried to change the type of columns ['start'] and ['end'] to pandas' datetime64 and using pd.to_datetime. Then, created a presidents['GDP'] = '' column to later add the corresponding GDP values using comparison. However, I am stuck after that. The problem is, I have no idea how to combine GDP by president's term.

Comment: Should the GDP for 1953 be allocated to Truman or Eisenhower?

Comment: To Eisenhower, since Truman ended in the first month of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#sample data by years
np.random.seed(2023)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':range(1933, 2022),
                    'GDP':np.random.randint(10, size=89)})

#convert both columns to datetimes
df2['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])

#convert to years
df2['year'] = df2['start'].dt.year
y = df2['end'].dt.year

#create mapping Series   
s = df1.set_index('date')['GDP']

#repeat indices by difference of years
df = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(y.sub(df2['year']).add(1))]

#add counter and mapping by GDP Series
df['year'] = df['year'].add(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).map(s)
```

---

```
print (df.tail(10))
       start        end      president       party  year
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09  Richard Nixon  Republican     8
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09  Richard Nixon  Republican     4
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09  Richard Nixon  Republican     1
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09  Richard Nixon  Republican     7
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09  Richard Nixon  Republican     6
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20   Donald Trump  Republican     2
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20   Donald Trump  Republican     8
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20   Donald Trump  Republican     6
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20   Donald Trump  Republican     7
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20   Donald Trump  Republican     6
```

---

```
#last aggregate sum
df2['GDP'] = df.groupby(level=0)['year'].sum()
print (df2)
       start        end              president       party  year  GDP
0 1933-03-04 1941-01-20  Franklin D. Roosevelt  Democratic  1933   47
1 1945-04-12 1953-01-20        Harry S. Truman  Democratic  1945   32
2 1953-01-20 1961-01-20   Dwight D. Eisenhower  Republican  1953   20
3 1961-01-20 1963-11-22        John F. Kennedy  Democratic  1961    3
4 1963-11-22 1969-01-20      Lyndon B. Johnson  Democratic  1963   30
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09          Richard Nixon  Republican  1969   34
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20           Donald Trump  Republican  2017   29
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by columns with ranges of years should working nice too, because small dataset:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':range(1933, 2022),
                    'GDP':np.random.randint(10, size=89)})

df2['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])

y1 = df2['start'].dt.year
y2  = df2['end'].dt.year

s = df1.set_index('date')['GDP']

y3 = [range(s, e+1) for s, e in zip(y1, y2)]

df = df2.assign(year=y3).explode('year').assign(GDP=lambda x: x['year'].map(s))

df2['GDP'] = df.groupby(level=0)['GDP'].sum()
print (df2)
       start        end              president       party  GDP
0 1933-03-04 1941-01-20  Franklin D. Roosevelt  Democratic   47
1 1945-04-12 1953-01-20        Harry S. Truman  Democratic   32
2 1953-01-20 1961-01-20   Dwight D. Eisenhower  Republican   20
3 1961-01-20 1963-11-22        John F. Kennedy  Democratic    3
4 1963-11-22 1969-01-20      Lyndon B. Johnson  Democratic   30
5 1969-01-20 1974-08-09          Richard Nixon  Republican   34
6 2017-01-20 2021-01-20           Donald Trump  Republican   29
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason to use random numbers instead of just leaving the GDP column blank? Also, if I had a larger dataset, will Dataframe.explode still work?

Comment: @Jagernout1985 - Reason is because I want test some data, because in question are only years `1933, 2005`. If larger Dataset use first solution, it is faster.